# Logout BasicAuth in node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, basic-authentication

i have reference for http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-basic-authentication

my code conect my database mongodb:

```
var admin = express.basicAuth(authentikasi);
function authentikasi(user, pass, callback) {

    // declrare my database mongodb
    db.collection('ak_admin', function (err, data) {
        data.findOne({'adm_name': {'$regex': user}}, function (err, level) {
            if (level == null) {
                console.log('Nilai database Administrator masuk Null ulangi login');
                callback(null);

            } else {
                var a = level.adm_name;
                var b = level.adm_password;
                var c = level.adm_mobile; 

                if (user === a && pass === b) {
                    callback(null, {name: a, id: c});
               } else
                    callback(null, false);
            }
        });
    });
};


 app.get('/admin', admin, function(req, res){
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/admin/index.html');
});
```

my schema for login basicauth is succesfull but my question : how to create logout because my site admin have login after use this schema not input username and password again :

```
    app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    //how code in here for erase memory in variable admin (user and pass)   
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');

});
```

please help me thanks you...

Comment: Have you found a solution by any chance? I am trying to do the same thing! Thanks.